# How to encourage people to put up more bounties for questions

Tags: discussion, bounty, community, engagement

This is related to an existing question [How to encourage questions](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1347/how-to-encourage-questions) but my focus here is specifically on getting people to post bounties.

I understand that there are some issues with the bounty system that might also be counterproductive to the outcome that I am trying to achieve here, but I have always seen the need on UXSE to resolve certain things like:

- Engagement from both new and slightly experienced users finding it hard to gain XP
- Questions that remain unanswered even though they are relevant and do deserve a lot more attention
- Questions that are not improved after a bounty has been offered
- People having accumulated lots of XP which should be redistributed back to the community

Has this issue been looked at further, and are there examples from other StackExchange sites that we can learn from?